# Filtering SNMP View

Tags: linux, networking, snmp

We have several network interfaces in a machine. How to configure SNMP view to limit which interfaces could be shown to public community?

We're using Ubuntu Server and default SNMPD from the repository. We have successfully limit the SNMPD agent to show only `interfaces` tree using this configuration:

```
view system included  .iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.interfaces
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the mask parameter. See [snmpd.conf wiki page](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Vacm#VACM_Masks.2C_or_How_to_restrict_access_to_a_particular_index_.28row.29_in_a_Table) for further explanation.

This will allow user to see only the second row in the ifTable:

```
view system included  .iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifIndex.2 ff.a0
```

or in the shorter form:

```
                      # OID                          # mask
view system included .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.2          ff.a0
#             ignore those with 0(a = 1 0 1 0)
#             allow any column in table ^  
#             restrict access to the second row
```